# Changing the initialization location of Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp, dot-emacs

I used to take the Programming languages course on Coursera and for the sake of the course i installed SML-Mode.

Now, I'd want to set up a Clojure environment in Emacs but instead of initializing Emacs from ~/.emacs.d, it initializes from the Users/karthik/Documents/sml-mode/sml-mode-startup

I deleted the sml-mode folder and on Emacs startup it shows me a warning about the files not being present. How I do point Emacs to load Emacs Live from the home folder.

I'm an Emacs newbie.

Comment: Are you saying that Emacs was supplied as one of the components of the SML software you installed? Or did you install Emacs yourself, and this SML-mode was an independent package? If the former, I would suggest leaving it alone and installing standard Emacs alongside it. If the latter, you should at least link to the software so people have some idea what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it, is

save you closure settings in `/some/dir/my-closure-settings.el` and call emacs as the following (to learn about `-q` `-l` , try `emacs --help` )

```
$ emacs -q -l /some/dir/my-closure-settings.el
```

or even placing an alias in `bashrc`,

```
$ alias closure-emacs='emacs -q -l /some/dir/my-closure-settings.el'
$ closure-emacs # will start emacs with your closure settings.
```

As you progress in learning some elisp, you will want to do it in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed Emacs yourself, and this SML-mode was an independent package, then I would speculated that it may have modified your `site-start.el`.

See if running `emacs --no-site-file` makes a difference.

If that's the issue, you can visit the file with:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(find-library site-run-file)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You might also check:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `user-emacs-directory` <kbd>RET</kbd>

when running emacs in various ways:

- `emacs`
- `emacs --no-site-file`
- `emacs -q`
- `emacs -Q`

Unless it's a custom binary, at some point it should tell you `"~/.emacs.d/"`

Answer (score 0):

Installing SML-mode does not change the place of the main initialization file, which is one of `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.  So look at those files (which ever of the two is present), and if none is present, then just create it and add what you need in it.

BTW, it looks like you're using an old `sml-mode` package (the newer one doesn't have an `sml-mode-startup.el` file).  So please try and make sure the documentation that pointed you to that mode is updated: nowaday `sml-mode` should be installed from GNU ELPA, i.e. via `M-x package-list` or `M-x package-install`.